# Dom Clobbering methods on the document object

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm struggling to understand how this flavor of dom clobbering actually works.

The green box at the top of this [section of the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#named-access-on-the-window-object) makes it pretty clear why I can access HTML elements as global variables on the window object. What I don't understand is why, in chrome, setting a tag's `name` attribute will overwrite javascript methods. For example,

```
<img name=getElementById>
```

I get

```
document.getElementById()
VM5014:1 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById is not a function
```

Can someone help me understand how the name attribute of an img tag overwrites methods on the document object?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the community. First of all, if you want to access an element by ID you need to specify the element name or id in between the brackets as a variable or as a string with either double quotemarks or a single one. From both ends obviously.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you look at some code in different ways before and after the attack:

If you have:

```
document.getElementById(id)
```

This calls `getElementById()` on the site (cf [Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)). Which gets you the element for a specific id if present.

But what if the function `getElementById` can be overwritten?
This is the case if you create an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) at `document`. You can do that using multiple name attributes (cf. [DOM clobbering in sanitized MD causes errors](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/36104)):

```
<img name="getElementById" src="">
<img name="getElementsByTagName" src="">
```

After that `document.getElementById()` will go to nowhere and the site could fail if this frequent used function is used.

For a deeper understanding also refer to this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67064756/dom-clobbering-and-how-it-works).